# Unable to sign users in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to sign users into my online website, however for some reason it seems that it isn't working.

I've tried checking to see if accounts are successfully being created - yes they are. I searched all over online to see if there are different ways to sign people in - there are, but none worked.

Here is the code that signs the user in

```
function signin() {
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorCode);
    console.log(errorMessage);
    // ...
  });
}
```

This is the code that should update the text on the page to say the user is "Logged in" (but it doesn't change)

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    document.getElementById("useremail").innerHTML = "Logged in";
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    document.getElementById("useremail").innerHTML = "Not logged in";
  }
});
```

The above code should sign the user in, and then display "Logged in" on the website. However, after attempting to sign in it still just displays "Not logged in"

(I've posted a similar question before, this time I've attempted to make my question clearer)

Comment: put a logger statement inside `if (user) {` and check if it is going there

Comment: Could you give your example on https://codepen.io It will be easier to debug

Comment: @brk i put loggers into the part that fired when they are signed in, and when they are not.
And it only logs "not signed in"